# Can I reuse a SSD if I forgot the ATA password?

Tags: ssd, disk-encryption, self-encrypting-drive, ata-security

I want to use the hardware encryption of my Samsung Evo 850 SSD. I understood that I will have to set an ATA password in the BIOS.

What happens if I forget the password (apart from the data loss)? Is the drive permanently bricked or can I still issue an erase command that will restore it to factory state?

Comment: Resetting the ata password is the same as issuing a secure erase. Reformat drive and use again

Comment: But I have an old ATA password-locked HDD, and the BIOS won't let me boot without the password when it's plugged in. I can't even go into the UEFI setup, so I can't issue a secure erase command. Also, secure erase and formatting are completely different things (ATA security is managed by the drive's firmware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1062333/how-to-unlock-an-ata-password-locked-hdd-with-an-upper-case-password-if-the-bios), I succeeded in resetting an HDD, but only with the drive's user password.

Assuming ATA security works the same on SSDs, the answer to this question seems to be no: The firmware will not work without the password.