# retrieving hash file from locked ssd so that i can use again

Tags: ssd

I would like to gain access to a hard drive that I got locked out of. I can show proof of ownership if you'd like.  I've heard of brute forcing hdd's and installed john the ripper.  Now I believe I need to get my hands on the hash file which contains the password.
What are your preferred methods of doings so.  It is a 60$ ssd that I would like to crack out of interest more than anything else, but also need.
I tried calling support 8 times. Got answered twice and their reactions were odd. I was asked to call other numbers and no one knew anything about ssd support nor where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If this SSD was locked by firmware, you will have a few attempts (3 to 5) to be able to guess/brute-force it, after that firmware will erase everything on it, so forget about john-the-ripper :)

If you simply want to unlock your drive(accepting that everything will be removed), look here:

[How to unlock an ATA password-locked HDD with an upper-case password if the BIOS accepts only lower-case?](https://superuser.com/questions/1062333/how-to-unlock-an-ata-password-locked-hdd-with-an-upper-case-password-if-the-bios)

Comment: Tyvm for the input. I forgot to type that the password was gained from a paper with random letters printed on it that I draw a line through and use to make my passwords. I must've typed the wrong key on both entries when setting it up while somewhat tied.

Comment: That link showed how to attempt entering a pw through a different program hoping it would help. I'm trying to brutforce every version of the password I should've typed and a possible mistype of keys that are near the key I was supposed to press of every character