# Hard Disk Password (HDP) - format SSD

Tags: hard-drive, passwords, disk-encryption

I just bought a Lenovo X1 Carbon (1st gen) via eBay with an unknown hard disk password (HDP) SSD. I can only enter the BIOS when the SSD is unplugged, otherwise this icon shows up after the Lenovo screen:

[image: 1 over cylinder next to a lock, with a dash on the far right]

I haven't found much on the internet about a HDP (hard disk password). This is the only place I found the image at all: [Joe in Australia's website](https://web.archive.org/web/20170208161048/http://www.ja.axxs.net/read_this_first!.htm).
The only solution suggested there is to replace the entire SSD. As with the X1C1 it requires an adapter to plugin a new drive, which is shipped from Asia in 1-2 months. Also, such an adapter only works for a new mSata/m.2 SSD to be plugged into the notebook, not to plug in the locked SSD into another board.

I already setup a Unetbootin USB drive and read about [hdparm](https://superuser.com/questions/1062333/how-to-unlock-an-ata-password-locked-hdd-with-an-upper-case-password-if-the-bios), however this requires a hot-pluggable SSD. It seems that this notebook doesn't support this (no option for this, AHCI is enabled) as when plugging the SSD in a running Unetbnootin-USB-Ubuntu system, it isn't recognized (`fdisk -l` only shows the usb stick).
Also changed the bootorder to boot from the USB first, but with the SSD in, the icon shows up again.

Is there a way to format the SSD?

---

I found [this blogpost](http://jbeekman.nl/blog/2015/03/lenovo-thinkpad-hdd-password) where with an password you could unlock the ssd within another pc.

I also checked some default master-passwords for the ssd (sandisk sd5sg2-256g-1052e) 'sandisk123', 'ssd123' and 'test' without any luck.

Comment: Did you contact the seller and ask for the password?

Comment: Did you remove the disk (as recommended by the linked page) to see if any other passwords are required?

Comment: But you wrote that you can enter the BIOS? Why would you need a hot pluggable HDD to use hdparm? Did you try to access the disc on another system?

Comment: @Seth I can enter the Bios when the SSD is unplugged, but then I cant format the SSD because it isn't recognized in Ubuntu (atleast with `fdisk`, I guess hot-plugging isnt available). When its plugged in, it wont boot from the Unetbootin USB, i immediately get the icon. I already changed the boot-order to USB at first, but this denst have had anny effect. I also cannot plugin the SSD into another PC as the X1C1 SSD got a nonstandard connector.

Comment: So you did plug in the drive after booting Ubuntu?  To make it show up, try opening a terminal, run `sudo -s` to become root, then `echo '- - -' > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan` to force it to look for the new drive.

Comment: @psusi Nothing happens. Nothing print to the terminal, and no new drive or similarappeared in the filesystem/desktop

Comment: @nonsensation, it won't appear on the desktop, but should show up in `lsblk` or `dmesg` that the drive was found.  You also might have multiple host controllers in which case you may need to use host1, host2, etc instead of host0.

Comment: @psusi Thanks. This shows only the loop0 and sda1 as my USB drive, the ssd isnt detected. The only option seems to hot-plug the ssd, as mentioned [here](http://jbeekman.nl/blog/2015/03/lenovo-thinkpad-hdd-password/#isso-10) the password is promted before starting up the bios at all.

Comment: Yes, but after plugging it in, it *should* show up.. especially after running that command.

Comment: @psusi well, the SSD itself is heated up.. Maybe it is the Lenovo itself doesnt support hot-plugging the SSD at all?

Comment: All SATA controllers support hot plugging, even if they don't provide the notification that makes them auto detect.  Hence the command to force the scan.

Comment: Incase you hsvent noticed, it is hardware encrypted. It wont talk to u unless with a password

Comment: "I found this blogpost" - I just quickly scanned but it still requires the password. I still think only way is replace the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Reset forgotten hard disk password

If you forget the user hard disk password, or both user and master hard disk passwords, Lenovo cannot reset your passwords or recover data from the hard disk drive. You must take your computer to a Lenovo Service Provider to have the hard disk drive replaced.

https://support.lenovo.com/nl/en/solutions/ht036206

There are services that may be able to remove passwords but AFAIK they require the computer to be shipped so that firmware can be re-flashed.

Answer (score -1):

This is Lenovos HDD encryption feature. It doesn't encrypt the contents of a disk, but it makes it so the drive controller will refuse to do anything unless you enter the password.

That means, it wont show up in most recovery tools. The data is still in cleartext on the disk, but it will refuse to talk to the computer before it gets its password.