How to send the harddisk password to an SATA HDD that is connected via a USB Adapter?
Using powershell on Win 11 could I send the password to my harddisk which is connected through and USB-SATA-Adapter?
I have a USB-SATA-Adapter for my HDD and SSD. (JMicron Tect SCSI Service) in the hardware manager on Win 11)
The HDD and SSD have a hardware password set. The HDD starts spinning when connected, but is not accessible in any way. I strongly assume it's because of the password.
Researching the internet I found there are some websites (smartmontools; USB-attached-SCSI; about hdparm; predominantly for settings and commands on Linux derivates) about this, and even an dedicated command definition, how to send data/commands from Win 11 to the USB-Device, which send the data/command as SATA command to the harddisc. The USB-Device has to support some special command, and I saw a table that those JMicron devices support it.
Sadly there is nowhere an example ordefintion to find how to send the password through this SCSI-SATA connection.
I assume it's possible by using powershell in Win 11. I also could start knoppix and most other linux systema from a USB-stick on my laptop, and would therefor also be happy with command line code/help!

On a Linux operating system (I used Knoppix running from a USB-stick) I first opened the filemanager to look for the name, in my case 'sdb'. Then I opened the terminal and used
hdparm --security-unlock "Password" /dev/sdb
hdparm -I /dev/sdb | sed -n /^Security/,\$p

Because I could not access the drive in the filemanager because of now a "corrupted block", I assumed it was because of the Windows Hibernation state that harddisc was on.
So I used
hdparm --security-disable "password" /dev/sdb

which I found on https://superuser.com/a/1062348/540538, to later use the harddisc without password when running Win 11 again.
I ran the first two commands with sudo in front, just because I found it that way somewhere else. The third I tried without sudo in front, which didn't work, then with sudo , and it worked then. (Obviously I have not too great knowledge about Linux. Someone might edit here and add some real knowledge here.)
I can now access the harddisc using the USB adapter when running Win 11.
There are also at least two programs for windows that could do this according to what I read. I didn't try them, as I didn't need them anymore:

The smartmontools, a collection of software to use in a cmd.exe or nowadays powershell window.
A programm called Victoria SSD/HDD. But I wasn't happy about that program's integrity, though it's downloadable on some reputable download sites, and declared as save.



The USB-Device has to support some special command, and I saw a table that those JMicron devices support it.

That's generally for older JMicron devices. New USB-SATA adapters tend to support the standard 'SAT' pass-through method as defined in T10 "SCSI/ATA Translation".

Sadly there is nowhere an example ordefintion to find how to send the password through this SCSI-SATA connection.

On Linux, you would use the regular method with hdparm. It will automatically use the SCSI I/O functions to send the ATA commands within SCSI "ATA pass through" packets.
hdparm --security-unlock "Foo" /dev/sdc

hdparm -I /dev/sdc | sed -n /^Security/,\$p

In fact it will do so even for directly SATA-connected HDDs, because Linux nowadays treats all ATA disks (even PATA ones!) as if they were SCSI disks on a special 'libata' controller, so all ATA-specific tools have learned to use SCSI ATA Passthrough when needed.
On Windows, however: I don't think you can. Although it has a similar "raw SCSI I/O" feature, I recall it being even explicitly mentioned on Microsoft's website that the OS filters the ATA 'security' commands from being sent through this facility. (It definitely performs such filtering for directly-connected ATA devices.)
So if you must do this from Windows – you'll likely need to start a Linux VM within VirtualBox and use its "USB passthrough" feature to attach the entire USB-SATA adapter to the VM, where you can run hdparm on it.

I'll try it in the coming few days on a Linux system started from an USB-stick, and then report back! Thank you so much!

@John Most USB "sticks" (as in, thumb drives; although not all) are not (S)ATA drive behind a USB bridge though.

Just in case your machine still has USB2.0 ports: Don't use those, the old EHCI/OHCI controllers might not support the required protocols for SAT/UASP yet.
The (typically blue) USB3 / SuperSpeed ports (using XHCI controllers) should support it.

@Manawyrm: SAT support doesn't require UASP support; it can work over the basic mass-storage mode (which is also SCSI).

Good news first: It worked somehow! :) First I used your two commands (for 'sdb' in my case), but I couldn't access the harddisc in Knoppix: The filemanager said some block is corrupted. I assumed it could be of the Windows Hibernation on that disc. So I looked for disabling the password altogether and found 'hdparm --security-disable "password" /dev/sdb' (https://superuser.com/a/1062348/540538) -- I used 'sudo ' in front of the first two commands, but only because i found it that way somewhere else. The third I tried without 'sudo ', which didn't work, then with 'sudo ',which worked. (I have

... I have not too great knowledge of Linux obviously :) --- I'll wait a day before accepting your answer, in case you want to add the '--security-disable' command to your answer. Thank you so much! It saved my an enormous amount of time! (For clarification: I can now access the hdd via the adapter when using win 11. The password is disabled.)
